# Switching control between windows

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, window

I am new to selenium.I am trying to swtich the control between three windows i.e from window A to window B then from window B to window C. I am using the same code for both the above procedures and that code is:

```
`for(String winHandle : idriver.getWindowHandles()){
    idriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
     }`
```

The problem is that the control switches from window A to window B with this code, but when I use the same code to switch control from window B to window C, the code remains on the same window B. I tried the following:

`for(String winHandle : idriver.getWindowHandles()){
                    idriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                    System.out.println( idriver.switchTo().window(winHandle));
                }`

and the console printed:

`InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (5e2b3ada-0ee7-4540-9d94-d6f74e72b6bd)
InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (5e2b3ada-0ee7-4540-9d94-d6f74e72b6bd)
InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (5e2b3ada-0ee7-4540-9d94-d6f74e72b6bd)`

the same above was printed both times when switching window from A to B and then from B to C.

I am using Java, selenium , Win 8, IE 10.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the full code ....

i think you have find element from B to switch C window

after that you can close one by one ..i.e first close C window and B window ..and return to parent window

```
String handle=driver.getWindowHandle();//get handle of parent window
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();//get all window handles 
for(String han:handles)
{
if(!han.equals(handle)
{driver.switchTo().window(han);}
 }
```

Comment: @senthikumar : i have asked my question again in a explanatory way on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464718/switching-control-between-multiple-child-popups
please answer it if you understand it better there,thanks.

Comment: if possible, can i get a generic code that i can use, which uses the popup title to switch control between popups.