# Switching control between multiple child popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, popup

I have a parent window, it has only login fields, i have stored its control using:

`String parentWindow= idriver.getWindowHandle();`

when the login credentials are entered, a new popup(say "popup A") opens and my app runs in it.I have switched the control to this "popup A" using:

`for (String handle1 : idriver.getWindowHandles()) {
            idriver.switchTo().window(handle1);
            }`

Now, when i click a button in this popup A, a popup opens(say "Popup B"), i again used:

`for (String handle1 : idriver.getWindowHandles()) {
            idriver.switchTo().window(handle1);
            }`

and the control was transfered to this popup B.

The problem is now i want to swtich to a popup C but the code that worked for switching from parent window to Popup A and then from popup A to popup B is not working.

The control is left on popup B and does not get transfered to window C. Please help. I am using Java, selenium , Win 8, IE 10.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in `idriver.getWindowHandles()` is your parent window... you need to exclude existed windows.

```
    public String popupHandle(List<String> existingWindowHandles) {
    String popupHandle = null;
    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String handle : windowHandles) {
        for (String existingWindowHandle : existingWindowHandles) {
            if (!handle.equals(existingWindowHandle)) {
                popupHandle = handle;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return popupHandle;
}
```

using:

```
List<String> ignoreWindows = new ArrayList<String>();
String parentWindow = idriver.getWindowHandle();
ignoreWindows.add(parentWindow)
String popUpWindow = popupHandle(ignoreWindows);
idriver.switchTo().window(popUpWindow);
String currentWindow = idriver.getWindowHandle();
ignoreWindows.add(currentWindow);
// doing your code
// new popup appears
popUpWindow = popupHandle(ignoreWindows);
idriver.switchTo().window(popUpWindow);
```

I think this will help you, good luck.
P.S. i didn't try it sorry, i don't have near a hardware to try it.

Answer (score 0):

i have used the following and it worked for me:

```
`String windowTitle = "Popup C";
               Set<String> handles = idriver.getWindowHandles();

               for (String window : handles) {
                   Thread.sleep(200);
                   idriver.switchTo().window(window);
                   Set<String> mhandles = idriver.getWindowHandles();
                   for (String mwindow : mhandles) {

                   idriver.switchTo().window(mwindow);
                   System.out.println("Im in");
                   Thread.sleep(200);
                   if (idriver.getTitle().contains(windowTitle)) {
                       idriver.switchTo().window(mwindow);
                       System.out.println(windowTitle);
                       break;
                   }
                   }
               }`
```

if any one has a better suggestion, please feel free to add. thanks